# RxJava Relay vs Subjects

Tags: rx-java2

I'm trying to understand the purpose of this library by Jake Warthon: 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay

> Basically: A Subject except without the ability to call onComplete or
>   onError. Subjects are stateful in a damaging way: when they receive an
>   onComplete or onError they no longer become usable for moving data.

I get idea, it's a valid use case, but the above seems easy to achieve just using the existing subjects.

**1.** Don't forward `errors`/`completions` events to the subject:

```
`observable.subscribe({ subject.onNext(it) }, { log error / throw exception },{ ... })`
```

**2.** Don't expose the subject, make your method signature return an observable instead.

`fun(): Observable<> { return subject }`

I'm obviously missing something here and I'm very curios on what it is!

```
class MyPublishRelay<I> : Consumer<I> {

    private val subject: Subject<I> = PublishSubject.create<I>()

    override fun accept(intent: I) = subject.onNext(intent)

    fun subscribe(): Disposable = subject.subscribe()
    fun subscribe(c: Consumer<in I>): Disposable = subject.subscribe(c)
    //.. OTHER SUBSCRIBE OVERLOADS
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`subscribe` has overloads and, usually, people get used to the `subscribe(Consumer)` overload. Then they use subjects and suddenly `onComplete` is also invoked. RxRelay saves the user from themselves who don't think about the difference between `subscribe(Consumer)` and `subscribe(Observer)`.

> 1. Don't forward errors/completions events to the subject:

Indeed, but based on our experience with beginners, they often don't think about this or even know about the available methods to consider.

> 2. Don't expose the subject, make your method signature return an observable instead.

If you need a way to send items into the subject, this doesn't work. The purpose is to use the subject to perform item multicasting, sometimes from another `Observable`. If you are in full control of the emissions through the `Subject`, you should have the decency of not calling `onComplete` and not letting anything else do it either.

Comment: Thanks akarnokd, Good to know I'm not missing anything :) Regarding #2 if you put your subject inside wrapper class you can have a method accept(item) { subject.omNext(item) }. And The Subject remains a private field

Comment: Are you sure this is the only reason though?. Creating a whole new library just to avoid a beginners mistake seems like an overkill. So is importing it to your projects

Comment: You mean [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay/issues/30)? Since the internals are mostly the same as the standard Subjects, and removing the terminal event handling is not a significant performance win with either, that leaves us with what I wrote.

Comment: Yes ! I opened that issue after reading your answer :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Subjects have far more overhead because they have to track and handle
> terminal event states. Relays are stateless aside from subscription
> management.
>
> - Jake Wharton

(This is from the issue OP opened on GitHub and felt it was a more a correct answer and wanted to "relay" it here for others to see. https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay/issues/30)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@akarnokd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520617/3484700):

In some cases you can't control the flow of data inside the `Observable`, an example of this is when observing data changes from a database table using `Room` Database.

Answer (score -2):

If you use Subjects, executing `subjects.getValue` will always throw error about null safety. So you have to put "? or !!" everywhere in your code even though you know that it will be not nullable.

```
public T getValue() {
    Object o = value.get();
    if (NotificationLite.isComplete(o) || NotificationLite.isError(o)) {
        return null;
    }
    return NotificationLite.getValue(o);
}
```